# net.Socket.remoteAddress is undefined on connect in node js net module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to retrieve the IP address of a new socket on the client side.

like so

```
var socket = net.Socket()
console.log(socket.remoteAddress)
```

However, this prints `undefined` to the console

On the server side, socket.remoteAddress is exposed with no issues at all using this code.

```
net.createServer(function(socket){
     console.log(socket.remoteAddress, socket.remotePort)
}).listen(4000)
```

So my question is, am I experiencing a bug, or am I misunderstanding how Socket/TCP connections are handled.

I understand that in TCP, typically the client port is chosen at random, but I don't imagine this should make it undefined as I'm experiencing- and at the very least, the public IP should be available to the API so long as I'm connected to a network. Admittedly, I am a bit of a novice with networking, but this seems a bit weird.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting to get in the first example since there is no remoteAddress a newly created and therefore unconnected socket could return. Your 2nd example is in a listener function which is given connected sockets as they are accepted..

Comment: The test suite shows a client using remoteAddress correctly from its connect event on, maybe that is the answer to your question? https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8b4af64f50c5e41ce0155716f294c24ccdecad03/test/parallel/test-net-remote-address-port.js#L55

Comment: I was misunderstanding the purpose of remote and local address/port. Apparently remote address is the address of the host in a tcp connection, while local represents the client connecting to the host